# SAP ArchiveLink object cannot be opened

Tags: abap, sap-basis

I have requirement to make SF Spool to PDF and save with Archivelink,
I've used FMs:  `RSTS_GET_ATTRIBUTES`, `CONVERT_OTFSPOOLJOB_2_PDF`, `SCMS_XSTRING_TO_BINARY` then save to application server via Open Dataset.

For archiving part FMs are `ARCHIVOBJECT_CREATE_TABLE` and `ARCHIV_CONNECTION_INSERT`. Setup has been made by basis in OAC0 and I've setup the OAC2 and OAC3. Upon executing the program, TOA01 tables are having entries.

But when checking the PDF file using FM `ARCHIVOBJECT_DISPLAY` this error pops up

[image: adobe error]

When I'm trying to directly download the PDF file from application server to presentation layer it can be viewed normally.

What I am missing?

Comment: `then save to application server via Open Dataset` isn't saving file to AS a redundant step? why can't you send it to content server on-the-fly?

Answer (score 1):

Managed to solve after looking closely with data types
BINARCHIVOBJECT parameter from ARCHIVOBJECT_CREATE_TABLE is set at RAW1024 while
BINARY TAB parameter from SCMS_XSTRING_TO_BINARY is RAW128.

Executed cl_bcs_convert=>xstring_to_xtab